# ping failed error in connection testing : MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database using hibernate.

I'm testing the connection using this :

[image]

My wamp is installed on port number 80, my database name is hibernate_test, both my username and password are "ingenius".

I installed the mysql-connector-java-5.1.0-bin jar

I enabled remote Access to MySQL and WAMP Server by editing the c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\conf\httpd.conf file :

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    ExecCGI MultiViews
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all    
</Directory>
```

and I keep getting the `ping failed` error. I don't know where I'm wrong !!! Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your jdbc url to

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_test
```

and you should be through, as mysql's default port in 3306

Comment: Thank you! It's so obvious yet ... !! I apreciate the help Satya !

Comment: anytime, glad that  I could help

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple first u need to create a table.eg i created a table called TEST.Then i changed my jdbc url to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TEST(i.e.your table name) and then ping this will work(worked for me).

Answer (score 0):

You can try below URL`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<DB NAME>?characterEncoding=latin1&useConfigs=maxPerformance`